# Compare dataframe columns by row value & select the one with matched-pattern

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as shown below:

```
id1     id2     id3    id4    id5

9890    abc123  CI652  125    nan

156     CI951   9895   nan    nan

CI632   198     nan    nan    nan

nan     nan     145    nan    CI258

9892    9893    nan    nan    nan

abc556  nan     abc887 nan    CI642
```

I want to look through all the columns and select a value based on priority:

**abc* > 98* > anything except "nan" > nan**

Based on the value selected, I want to create & populate a new df / column. Expected output is as below:

```
id1     id2     id3    id4    id5    output

9890    abc123  CI652  125    nan    abc123

156     CI951   9895   nan    nan    9895

CI632   198     nan    nan    nan    CI632

nan     nan     145    nan    CI258  145

9892    9893    nan    nan    nan    9892

abc556  nan     abc887 nan    CI642  abc556
```

My logic is to iterate over each row in the df using a for-loop & then compare values by priority using some if-else logic

Is there a better way to achieve this? Any insights are appreciated. TIA!

Comment: For `nan` you need `nan as string` or `nan` as in `np.nan`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way, you have try with checking the conditions by `startswith` and rank them according to your priority , then use `df.lookup`:

```
m=df.astype(str)
```

---

```
c1=m.applymap(lambda x: x.startswith('abc'))*3
c2=m.applymap(lambda x: x.startswith('98'))*2
c3=df.notna().astype(int)
s=(c1+c2+c3).idxmax(1)
```

---

```
df=df.assign(output=df.lookup(s.index,s.values))
```

---

```
      id1     id2     id3    id4    id5  output
0    9890  abc123   CI652  125.0    NaN  abc123
1     156   CI951    9895    NaN    NaN    9895
2   CI632     198     NaN    NaN    NaN   CI632
3     NaN     NaN     145    NaN  CI258     145
4    9892    9893     NaN    NaN    NaN    9892
5  abc556     NaN  abc887    NaN  CI642  abc556
```

Comment: I was about to go with this direction, except that I use `stack` instead of `applymap`

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry for the late reply(was driving back home), thats a good suggestion, if you want you can write an answer :)

Comment: @KrunalPatel No problem. happy coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

- here is the solution.
- basic idea is to use pandas apply function for each row `(axis=0)`.
- match with priority and return

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import re
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a':['abc','2',np.nan,'23423af'], 'b':['98564','98ad456',np.nan,'ab23452fdsa']})
    a           b
0   abc        98564
1   2          98ad456
2   NaN        NaN
3   23423af    ab23452fdsa
>>> def isna(x): # helper function to check nan
    return x!=x

>>> def match_pattern(x): # your priority matching function
    for val in x:
        if isna(val):
            continue
        if re.match('^abc.*',val):
            return val
    for val in x:
        if isna(val):
            continue
        if re.match('^98.*',val):
            return val
    for val in x:
        if  not isna(val):
            return val
    return x[0]

>>> df['output']=df.apply(lambda x:match_pattern(x), axis=1)
>>> df
    a         b          output
0   abc     98564        abc
1   2       98ad456      98ad456
2   NaN     NaN          NaN
3   23423af ab23452fdsa  23423af
```

PS: @anky_91 's answer is good and concise. This is just one more way to do it.